# What is the difference between Hela and Mistress Death?

Tags: marvel, character-similarity

I seriously couldn't figure out the difference between Hela, the sister of Thor and daughter of Odin, who is the **Goddess of Death** and Mistress Death, who is often seen in comics in conjunction with Thanos and Deadpool.

Do they have similar powers? And if yes then why is Hela called the "Goddess of Death", when Mistress Death also has similar powers?

Answer (score 4):

Hela is an Asgardian, same as Thor and Odin. Death, also known as Mistress or Lady Death, is a completely separate entity - a cosmic entity that is the personification of death, come to collect the souls of those who have died.

Hela is referred to as the Goddess of Death because all Asgardians are considered to be Gods, Thor is the God of Thunder, Loki is the God of Mischief. This comes from the abilities they possess. Hela's abilities are, as her title suggests, incredibly powerful in that she can [simply kill people at will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hela_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities).

> While Hela's touch is fatal to mortals as well and she is capable of stealing their souls into Hel, she generally did not claim the souls of mortal heroes, leaving that task to the Valkyries who took the souls of heroes to Valhalla.

She rules over the realm of Hel, but beyond that, she's just another Asgardian

Lady/Mistress Death only appears to those who are dying, with the exception of Thanos, who is powerful enough to almost be considered another [Cosmic Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_entity_(Marvel_Comics)). She often appears before Deadpool as well, where they will often go on dates every time he reaches the brink of death.

Comment: Worth noting that each of the pantheons of gods seems to have their own realm of the dead (Hela: Hel and Valhalla; Pluto: Hades). Also, there are a number of variations on Hell in the Marvel universe, ruled over by different individuals who may claim to be Satan. Mephisto is the one who's seen most often, but there are others. Daimon Hellstrom and Satana's father was (originally, at least) not Mephisto, for instance. As you say, Mistress Death is a cosmic entity, and is *not* associated with an afterlife.

Answer (score -2):

I think Hela is Mistress or Lady Death. In *Thor: Ragnarok* when she's choking Thor and introduces herself as the Goddess of Death. She is referring to herself as Death itself. Then Thor hits her with the biggest lightning blast in the history of lightning.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Your answer is a bit confusing; you appear to be saying that because she calls herself "Goddess of Death," that automatically means she is "Mistress Death."  But that's the opposite of what the question is asking; what is the _difference_ between them?  Even if the same being fills both roles, they can be different aspects.  You should read [answer] for assistance in writing answers that better fit the question.

Answer (score -2):

They both are very different entities but I think in the MCU Hela is Mistress Death as that explains how Thanos got his Uru sword and Hela did say she was conquering worlds with Odin. Maybe that happened around Thanos’s world and they trained him, that’s why Odin abandoned Hela because he saw what they were becoming.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What you seem to be saying - that they are the same person - contradicts the premise of the question.  If you have *evidence* that they are in fact the same being, you should cite it.  Please read [answer].

Comment: this theory seems highly unlikely to be true.